# How to force GCC compiler to calculate constant values at compile time?

Tags: gcc, compilation, macros, constants, avr

I have the following code (CPU Atmel AVR ATmega64A):

```
#define UO_ADC1023  265
#define UREF_180V   (1023*180/UO_ADC1023)
....
if(ADC > UREF180) {do_something();}
```

This should evaluate `UREF_180V` as 694.87... and than this value should be rounded (better) to 695 or floored (poorer) to 694 to be compared to ADC register.

However I have `integer overflow` warning at compile. As per this I suppose that compiler generating code which calculates `(1023*180/UO_ADC1023)` at the run time which is very bad in my case.

I'd like to avoid to calculate those constants by my self (`#define UREF_180V 695` in this case I could be sure that they are really literals) to make the code more flexible and readable. I'd like also to be able to check those values after the compiler.

So the questions are:

1. Is there any possibility to force GCC compiler to calculate such constants at compile time?
2. How to check this calculated value?

Comment: Does your compiler chain support C++11?

Comment: @weltensturm, I'm not sure :( Compiler settings screenshot: https://goo.gl/glQjfd

Answer (score 3):

Macros are inserted at the place of invokation, where their content can later be compiled.

In C++11 you can evaluate expressions at compile time with `constexpr`, like this:

```
constexpr auto UREF_180V = 1023*180/UO_ADC1023;
```

Due to all of the numbers being `int`s the result of this is `694`. To properly round it you would have to change one of the values to a floating point number and create a `constexpr` rounding function, which can be invoked at compile time.

As for checking the number you could use `static_assert(695 == UREF_180V, "");`.

To compile C++11 code add `-std=c++11` to your compiler options. (You probably have to switch to a C++ project, and I'm not entirely certain AtmelStudio supports C++11, if not I'm sorry)

Comment: I'm not sure that I can use С++11 in my tool chain. How can I use C++11 extension? I should change my toolchain? Or I can "turn it on" by any command line option?

Comment: First you'll have to check if compiling plain C++ is possible. Create a .cpp file and try to compile it. If it doesn't work you probably have to switch to a C++ toolchain or create a new C++ project (I don't know how your IDE handles this). Once compiling C++ works, look for a compiler option text field and paste `-std=c++11` there and try to compile the code from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

`int` on AVR is 16-bit. Tell the compiler to use `long` instead (since 1023 * 180 will overflow).

```
#define UREF_180V   (1023L * 180 / UO_ADC1023)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful, but as far as I understand this is not a guarantiee for a compile time calculation?

Comment: I don't think there is any actual way to modify GCC's behavior either way; it *always* calculates the value at compile-time if it can.

Answer (score 2):

see the -fmerge-all-constants command, -fgcse, -fsee, or better, see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

nonetheless, the integer overflow can be part of an semantic error in your code as welternsturm mentioned

Comment: I'm not really familiar with such compiler thin tuning... Could you advize if I should use all three of those commands or I should choose one or couple depend on which will work for me? I have read the description via the link you provided me but the descriptions are very short and I have not enough knowledges to choose it my self :(

Comment: In addition: I can not edit command like options in the IDE's project options. Here is the screenshot: goo.gl/glQjfd Do you know how can I edit compiler options in Atmel Studio?

Comment: gcc has various levels of compiler optimizations, O0, 01, O2, O3, Os, among others. In each level there are individuals optimizations, like the three i put above, and yes, you must choose one or couple depend of which work better for your purpose, but, if you want, you can use a level, like O2 per example, which have all compiler optimization of O1, i.e O3 has all O2 optimization, etc. For each compiler options, example: -ftree-vrp, there is a command to turn it off,  example: -fno-tree-vrp. I don't know anything about Atmel Studio bro, i owe you, sorry.